# SOLR indexed item has extra word which is not available in query parameter - how to identify those cases?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

We have a scenario where we are trying to perform accurate name matching of Items using SOLR.

Query Parameter: Apple

---

SOLR Indexed Word: Apple-D

In our business case, "Apple" and "Apple-D" are totally different items and therefore SOLR shouldn't return the match.

Is there an option to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the fieldType used for the field. Use the String fieldType for the your field.

This String fieldType will make sure that the words will be stored as it is by solr.

It won't apply any analysis on the word. Or it won't create any tokes of it.

With the String type applied to it . The Apple and Apple-D are stored/indexed different token. As there won't be any tokenizing on the same. This will help you to achieve the exact match.

Once you change the fieldType. Re-index the same.

You can use the solr analysis tool to check how it is indexing and querying .

Note : Make sure whenever you ask question on it, Share your schema.xml

Comment: Thanks @Abhijit  We use field type as text_en_splitting. We need SOLR to split into TOKENS because for "query:Apple D" and "indexed:Apple-D" should match but "query:Apple" and "indexed:Apple-D" or "indexed:Apple D" shouldn't. Quite complicated but that's how the data that we deal with

Comment: try with WordDelimiterFilterFactory in your fieldType ...you need to try many permutation and combination with attributes of it.. add the same any try analysing the same in solr tool...here a link for more https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory